# Jackson with JSON: Unrecognized field, not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, json, data-binding, jackson

I need to convert a certain JSON string to a Java object. I am using Jackson for JSON handling. I have no control over the input JSON (I read from a web service). This is my input JSON:

```
{"wrapper":[{"id":"13","name":"Fred"}]}
```

Here is a simplified use case:

```
private void tryReading() {
    String jsonStr = "{\"wrapper\"\:[{\"id\":\"13\",\"name\":\"Fred\"}]}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
    Wrapper wrapper = null;
    try {
        wrapper = mapper.readValue(jsonStr , Wrapper.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("wrapper = " + wrapper);
}
```

My entity class is:

```
public Class Student { 
    private String name;
    private String id;
    //getters & setters for name & id here
}
```

My Wrapper class is basically a container object to get my list of students:

```
public Class Wrapper {
    private List<Student> students;
    //getters & setters here
}
```

I keep getting this error and "wrapper" returns `null`. I am not sure what's missing. Can someone help please?

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: 
    Unrecognized field "wrapper" (Class Wrapper), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1198891; line: 1, column: 13] 
    (through reference chain: Wrapper["wrapper"])
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException
    .from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
```

Comment: I found this useful to avoid creating a wrapper class: `Map dummy<String,Student> = myClientResponse.getEntity(new GenericType<Map<String, Student>>(){});` and then `Student myStudent = dummy.get("wrapper");`

Comment: JSON should looks like: String jsonStr = "{\"students\"\:[{\"id\":\"13\",\"name\":\"Fred\"}]}";  if you are expecting Wrapper object in your REST POST request

Comment: Related (but different) question: [Ignoring new fields on JSON objects using Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson)

Comment: And incidentally, most answers to _this_ question actually answer a different question, namely one similar to the one I linke above.

Comment: **majority of answers help brush problem under rug rather than actually solving it** :(

Comment: It is so funny that why so many answers in this questions answer the things that are not related to the questions ?  Apparently , the OP does not want to ignore deserialising the "wrapper" property ........

Comment: @NoobEditor sometimes you can only fix what's under your control, and the rest you have to ignore

Answer (score 1395):

You can use Jackson's class-level annotation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties

@JsonIgnoreProperties
class { ... }
```

It will ignore every property you haven't defined in your POJO. Very useful when you are just looking for a couple of properties in the JSON and don't want to write the whole mapping. More info at [Jackson's website](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations). If you want to ignore any non declared property, you should write:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Comment: Ariel, is there any way to declare this external to the class?

Comment: I haven't done it but I believe that you can get somewhere in the annotations processing code and add the behavior programatically, although I can't think why you would like to do it. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I'm serializing classes that I do not own (cannot modify).  In one view, I'd like to serialize with a certain set of fields.  In another view, I want a different set of fields serialized (or perhaps rename the properties in the JSON).

Comment: i must add that you do need the `(ignoreUnknown = true)` when annotating your class otherwise it won't work

Comment: Julián, this is not the correct answer to the question of the OP. However, I suspect that people come here because they google how to ignore properties not defined in POJO and this is the first result, so they end up up-voting this and Suresh's response (thats what happened to me). Although the original question has nothing to do with wanting to ignore undefined properties.

Comment: this is a very stupid default setting imho, if you add a property to your api, the whole serialization fails

Comment: Why on earth did this answer get so many updates. This does not solve the problem, it just ignores it!!!

Comment: I don't understand the difference between these 2 syntaxes above - can someone explain?

Comment: @ycomp, these are not 2 syntaxes, `@JsonIgnoreProperties` is the annotation and `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` a possible way to use it. You can also specify which fields to ignore as stated on Jackson's documentation (e.g. `@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "extra", "uselessValue" })`)

Comment: I got to this stackoverflow post because of this error message in mongodb jackson library. In my case I did not need to add this `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation. I was just trying to make "_id" property work here as told in jackson tutorial http://mongojack.org/tutorial.html, but I coudn't. Since `@Objectd @JsonProperty("_id") public String getId(){return this._id}` do not work, I had to replace it with `@ObjectId @JsonProperty("_id") public String _id;`. Now the runtime error is gone and I am not using @JsonIgnoreProperties. The version is 1.4.2

Comment: Downvoted as it does not answer the OP's question. Ignoring unknown properties doesn't solve his problem, but leaves him with a `Wrapper` instance where the `students` list is `null` or empty.

Comment: If you don't want your application to respond to unknown props defaultly by throwing a 500 error and barfing out all your property names, then this is the correct answer. I really don't know why most would desire this default behavior.

Comment: @Ariel Kogan ,so how does it behave just using @ JsonIgnoreProperties, I find it's ok to compile

Comment: @yuxh, `ignoreUnknown` defaults to `false`. You can check the [documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#ignoreUnknown()).

Comment: FWIW after almost a decade, regarding @JonLorusso's question about annotating classes you do not own, take a look at Jackson Mixin (and the function addMixInAnnotations). It's meant exactly for that.

Comment: In my case I got this response because the resource anwers with 500 error. I setted with @JsonIgnoreProperties and then get null. I knew the problem was then REST.

Answer (score 756):

You can use

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

It will ignore all the properties that are not declared.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it still fails on unknown properties

Comment: Could u please paste atleast a piece of code what exactly u are doing, You might have missed something there..Either by doing this or by using "@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
" Your problem should be resolved. Anyways good luck.

Comment: I run this code: http://pastebin.com/rdBNezEn. However, I have realized that what this question asks is a bit different. Your answer is valid

Comment: FWIW -- I had to import this slightly different enum: org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES

Comment: ^Above is for Jackson versions prior to 2

Comment: You can also chain these calls like:  getObjectMapper().disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)

Comment: Downvoted as it does not answer the OP's question. Ignoring unknown properties doesn't solve his problem, but leaves him with a Wrapper instance where the students list is null or empty.

Comment: mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); worked for me

Answer (score 156):

The first answer is almost correct, but what is needed is to change getter method, NOT field -- field is private (and not auto-detected); further, getters have precedence over fields if both are visible.(There are ways to make private fields visible, too, but if you want to have getter there's not much point)

So getter should either be named `getWrapper()`, or annotated with:

```
@JsonProperty("wrapper")
```

If you prefer getter method name as is.

Comment: Please elaborate - which getter needs to be changed or annotated?

Comment: you mean annotated with @JsonGetter("wrapper"), right?

Comment: @pedrambashiri No, I mean `@JsonProperty`. While `@JsonGetter` is a legal alias, it is rarely used as `@JsonProperty` works for getters, setters and fields; setters and getters can be distinguished by signature (one takes no arguments, returns non-void; other takes one argument).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Sounds like Jackson has trouble mapping the source JSON to your POJO, but you can guarantee matches by tagging the getters. Thanks!

Answer (score 147):

using Jackson 2.6.0, this worked for me:

```
private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = 
    new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

or with the setting:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Comment: With that config annotation is unnecessary

Comment: Do you need to configure both ObjectMapper and Annotation on class? I guess objectMapper will fix for all, without a need to annotate each class. I use the annotation though.

Comment: You do not need both settings in the same class. You might also use DI to get a global singleton instance of the `ObjectMapper`, to set the `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` property globally.

Comment: You don't need both, you can choose one or the other.

Answer (score 83):

it can be achieved 2 ways:

1. Mark the POJO to ignore unknown properties

   ```
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
   ```
2. Configure ObjectMapper that serializes/De-serializes the POJO/json as below:

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper =new ObjectMapper();            
   // for Jackson version 1.X        
   mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
   // for Jackson version 2.X
   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
   ```

Comment: Why should this be the accepted answer? This just tells to ignore unknown properties, whereas the question was to find a way to get the json wrapped into an object which this solution clearly says to ignore.

Comment: Nice answer by simply using the first option.

Answer (score 71):

**Adding setters and getters solved the problem**, what I felt is the actual issue was how to solve it but not how to suppress/ignore the error.
I got the error "***Unrecognized field.. not marked as ignorable..***"

Though I use the below annotation on top of the class it was not able to parse the json object and give me the input

> @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

Then I realized that I did not add setters and getters, after adding setters and getters to the "Wrapper" and to the "Student" it worked like a charm.

Comment: This appears to be the only answer that actually answers the question. All the other answers are just marking unknown properties as ignored, but 'wrapper' is not an unknown property, it is what we are trying to parse.

Answer (score 47):

This just perfectly worked for me

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(
    DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation did not.

Comment: Downvoted as it does not answer the OP's question. Ignoring unknown properties doesn't solve his problem, but leaves him with a `Wrapper` instance where the students list is `null` or empty.

Answer (score 44):

This works better than All please refer to this property.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    projectVO = objectMapper.readValue(yourjsonstring, Test.class);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the one that solved my issue - which matched the title of this post.

Comment: Answers work well for me and it's very easy.Thank you

Comment: after this my projectVO data is null.yourjsonstring having value but projectVO  fields are null. Any help guys ?

Comment: this really works and the POJO also doesnt need any modifications!

Answer (score 35):

If you are using Jackson 2.0

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Comment: why this config has no effect for me?

Comment: @zhaozhi It depends on Jackson version

Answer (score 26):

According to the [doc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) you can ignore selected fields or all uknown fields:

```
 // to prevent specified fields from being serialized or deserialized
 // (i.e. not include in JSON output; or being set even if they were included)
 @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "internalId", "secretKey" })

 // To ignore any unknown properties in JSON input without exception:
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

Answer (score 20):

It worked for me with the following code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper =new ObjectMapper();    
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Answer (score 19):

Jackson is complaining because it can't find a field in your class Wrapper that's called "wrapper".  It's doing this because your JSON object has a property called "wrapper".

I think the fix is to rename your Wrapper class's field to "wrapper" instead of "students".

Comment: Thanks Jim. I tried that and it did not fix the problem. I am wondering if I am missing some annotation..

Comment: Hmm, what happens when you create the equivalent data in Java and then use Jackson to *write* it out in JSON.  Any difference between that JSON and the JSON above should be a clue to what's going wrong.

Comment: This answer worked for me, with the example from the question.

Answer (score 19):

I have tried the below method and it works for such JSON format reading with Jackson.
Use the already suggested solution of: annotating getter with `@JsonProperty("wrapper")`

Your wrapper class

```
public Class Wrapper{ 
  private List<Student> students;
  //getters & setters here 
}
```

My Suggestion of wrapper class

```
public Class Wrapper{ 

  private StudentHelper students; 

  //getters & setters here 
  // Annotate getter
  @JsonProperty("wrapper")
  StudentHelper getStudents() {
    return students;
  }  
} 


public class StudentHelper {

  @JsonProperty("Student")
  public List<Student> students; 

  //CTOR, getters and setters
  //NOTE: If students is private annotate getter with the annotation @JsonProperty("Student")
}
```

This would however give you the output of the format:

```
{"wrapper":{"student":[{"id":13,"name":Fred}]}}
```

Also for more information refer to https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations

Answer (score 16):

If you want to apply `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to all class in you application then the best way it is override Spring boot default jackson object.

In you application config file define a bean to create jackson object mapper like this.

```
@Bean
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return mapper;
    }
```

Now, you don't need to mark every class and it will ignore all unknown properties.

Comment: Why not just create a static method that does the same? What is the significance of creating a bean?

Answer (score 14):

This solution is generic when reading json streams and need to get only some fields while fields not mapped correctly in your Domain Classes can be ignored:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

A detailed solution would be to use a tool such as   jsonschema2pojo to autogenerate the required Domain Classes such as Student from the Schema of the json Response. You can do the latter by any online json to schema converter.

Answer (score 12):

Simple solution for Java 11 and newer:

```
var mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
        .disable(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
        .disable(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        .enable(ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
```

Important for ignoring is disabling 'FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES'

Comment: Note that in org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper, the method disable takes other parameters; you are referring here to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Answer (score 11):

Problem is your property in your JSON is called "wrapper" and your property in Wrapper.class is called "students".

So either...

1. Correct the name of the property in either the class or JSON.
2. Annotate your property variable as per StaxMan's comment.
3. Annotate the setter (if you have one)

Answer (score 11):

Annotate the field students as below since there is mismatch in names of json property and java property

```
public Class Wrapper {
    @JsonProperty("wrapper")
    private List<Student> students;
    //getters & setters here
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Somehow after 45 posts and 10 years, no one has posted the correct answer for my case.

```
@Data //Lombok
public class MyClass {
    private int foo;
    private int bar;

    @JsonIgnore
    public int getFoobar() {
      return foo + bar;
    }
}
```

In my case, we have a method called `getFoobar()`, but no `foobar` property (because it's computed from other properties).  `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on the class does not work.

The solution is to annotate the method with `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: What you should actually do here is ask the specific question for the issue you have had and then answer your own question with your solution.  What you have added here is not a solution to what the original question asks.  You will help a lot more people if you pose your specific issue as a question.

Comment: @DRaehal The primary purpose of Stackoverflow is not (just) to answer single-use questions, but to be a repository of useful questions and answers for future googlers. This is the first result on Google, hence the various answers.

Comment: Jeff Atwood would disagree with you.  
https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/#:~:text=%2DFounder%20(Former)-,The%20FAQ%20has%20contained%20one%20key%20bit%20of%20advice%20from,the%20form%20of%20a%20question.&text=it%20is%20OK%20to%20ask,a%20relevant%20Stack%20Exchange%20site.

Comment: Upvoted because this helped me out as well. After mucking around with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` and adding dummy members, I found this and it did exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this problem by simply changing the signatures of my setter and getter methods of my POJO class. All I had to do was change the **getObject** method to match what the mapper was looking for. In my case I had a **getImageUrl** originally, but the JSON data had **image_url** which was throwing the mapper off. I changed both my setter and getters to **getImage_url and setImage_url**.

Comment: you are right apparently: if the name you want is xxx_yyy
The way to call it would be getXxx_yyy and  setXxx_yyy.  This is very strange but it works.

Answer (score 7):

One other possibility is this property in the application.properties
`spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false`, which won't need any other code change in your application. And when you believe the contract is stable, you can remove this property or mark it true.

Answer (score 7):

This may not be the same problem that the OP had but in case someone got here with the same mistake I had then this will help them solve their problem. I got the same error as the OP when I used an ObjectMapper from a different dependency as the JsonProperty annotation.

This works:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
```

Does NOT work:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper; //org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.8.8
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; //com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.3
```

Comment: thanks! import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty worked for me instead the other:-)

Comment: omfg this was killing me! ty

Comment: This!! Wasted 1 hr trying to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me, was to make the property public.

Comment: It helps! Also class is better to do public.

Answer (score 6):

Either Change

```
public Class Wrapper {
    private List<Student> students;
    //getters & setters here
}
```

to

```
public Class Wrapper {
    private List<Student> wrapper;
    //getters & setters here
}
```

---- or ----

Change your JSON string to

```
{"students":[{"id":"13","name":"Fred"}]}
```

Answer (score 5):

For my part, the only line

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

didn't work too.

Just add

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

Jackson 2.4.0

Answer (score 5):

This worked perfectly for me

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of many of the existing answers.

Answer (score 5):

Your input

```
{"wrapper":[{"id":"13","name":"Fred"}]}
```

indicates that it is an Object, with a field named "wrapper", which is a Collection of Students. So my recommendation would be,

```
Wrapper = mapper.readValue(jsonStr , Wrapper.class);
```

where `Wrapper` is defined as

```
class Wrapper {
    List<Student> wrapper;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**The new Firebase Android introduced some huge changes ; below the copy of the doc :**

[https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android] **:**

**Update your Java model objects**

As with the 2.x SDK, Firebase Database will automatically convert Java objects that you pass to `DatabaseReference.setValue()` into JSON and can read JSON into Java objects using `DataSnapshot.getValue()`.

In the new SDK, when reading JSON into a Java object with `DataSnapshot.getValue()`, unknown properties in the JSON are now ignored by default so you no longer need `@JsonIgnoreExtraProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`.

To exclude fields/getters when writing a Java object to JSON, the annotation is now called `@Exclude` instead of `@JsonIgnore`.

```
BEFORE

@JsonIgnoreExtraProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class ChatMessage {
   public String name;
   public String message;
   @JsonIgnore
   public String ignoreThisField;
}

dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class)
```

---

```
AFTER

public class ChatMessage {
   public String name;
   public String message;
   @Exclude
   public String ignoreThisField;
}

dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class)
```

If there is an extra property in your JSON that is not in your Java class, you will see this warning in the log files:

```
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for ignoreThisProperty found on class com.firebase.migrationguide.ChatMessage
```

You can get rid of this warning by putting an `@IgnoreExtraProperties` annotation on your class. If you want Firebase Database to behave as it did in the 2.x SDK and throw an exception if there are unknown properties, you can put a `@ThrowOnExtraProperties` annotation on your class.

Answer (score 5):

set **public** your class fields not **private**.

```
public Class Student { 
    public String name;
    public String id;
    //getters & setters for name & id here
}
```

Comment: poor practice - this breaks the encapsulation.

Comment: Your class is in risk when user uses it because the internal state could be mutated through these fields.

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you cannot add the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotations to your class and you are inside a web server/container such as Jetty. You can create and customize the ObjectMapper inside a custom provider

```
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Provider
public class CustomObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> cls) {
        return getObjectMapper();
    }

    private synchronized ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        if(objectMapper == null) {
            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        }
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES** option is true by default:

```
FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES (default: true)
Used to control whether encountering of unknown properties (one for which there is no setter; and there is no fallback "any setter" method defined using @JsonAnySetter annotation) should result in a JsonMappingException (when enabled), or just quietly ignored (when disabled)
```

Answer (score 3):

The POJO should be defined as

Response class

```
public class Response {
    private List<Wrapper> wrappers;
    // getter and setter
}
```

Wrapper class

```
public class Wrapper {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    // getters and setters
}
```

and mapper to read value

```
Response response = mapper.readValue(jsonStr , Response.class);
```

Comment: Almost. Not `wrappers`, but `wrapper`.

Comment: @Frans Haha, thank you for catching the error. I naturally use plural for a collection. But per OP's question, it should be singular.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a very late response, but just changing the POJO to this should solve the json string provided in the problem (since, the input string is not in your control as you said):

```
public class Wrapper {
    private List<Student> wrapper;
    //getters & setters here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Google brought me here and i was surprised to see the answers... all suggested *bypassing* the error ( *which always bites back 4 folds later in developement* ) rather than solving it until [this gentleman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39784612/3154233) restored by faith in SO!

```
objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, TargetClass.class)
```

is used to convert a json String to an class object, whats missing is that the `TargetClass` should have public `get`ter / `set`ters. Same is missing in OP's question snippet too! :)

via [lombok](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/0.10.1) your class as below should work!!

```
@Data
@Builder
public class TargetClass {
    private String a;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties

Comment: Maybe some further explanations or doc would be nice

Comment: @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) works fine, thanks

Answer (score 3):

When we are generating getters and setters, specially which starts with 'is' keyword, IDE generally removes the 'is'. e.g.

```
private boolean isActive;

public void setActive(boolean active) {
   isActive = active;
}

public isActive(){
   return isActive;
}
```

In my case, i just changed the getter and setter.

```
private boolean isActive;

public void setIsActive(boolean active) {
   isActive = active;
}

public getIsActive(){
   return isActive;
}
```

And it was able to recognize the field.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue, only difference is i was working with YAML file instead of JSON file. So i was using YamlFactory() when creating an ObjectMapper. Also, the properties of my Java POJO were priviate.
However, the solution mentioned in all these answers did not help. I mean, it stopped throwing error and started returning Java object but the **properties of the java object would be null.**

I just did the following: -

```
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

And **without the need** of: -

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Now, i am able to deserialize data from Yaml file into Java object. All properties are not null now. This solution should work for JSON approach also.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was simple: the REST-service JSON Object was updated (a property was added), but the REST-client JSON Object wasn't. As soon as i've updated JSON client object the 'Unrecognized field ...' exception has vanished.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 1):

In my case a I have to add public getters and setters to leave fields private.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Application application = mapper.readValue(input, Application.class);
```

I use jackson-databind 2.10.0.pr3 .

Answer (score 1):

The shortest solution without setter/getter is to add `@JsonProperty` to a class field:

```
public class Wrapper {
    @JsonProperty
    private List<Student> wrapper;
}

public class Student {
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
}
```

Also, you called students list "wrapper" in your json, so Jackson expects a class with a field called "wrapper".

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else is using [force-rest-api](https://github.com/jesperfj/force-rest-api) like me, here is how I used this discussion to solve it (Kotlin):

```
var result = forceApi.getSObject("Account", "idhere")
result.jsonMapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,  false)
val account: Account = result.`as`(Account::class.java)
```

It looks like force-rest-api is using an old version of jackson's.

Answer (score 0):

You should just change the field of List from "students" to "wrapper" just the json file and the mapper will look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is not inline with the mapped class.
Change the input string

```
String jsonStr = "{\"students\"\:[{\"id\":\"13\",\"name\":\"Fred\"}]}";
```

Or change your mapped class

```
public class Wrapper {
    private List<Student> wrapper;
    //getters & setters here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case error came due to following reason

- Initially it was working fine,then i renamed one variable,made the
  changes in code and it gave me this error.
- Then i applied jackson ignorant property also but it did not work.
- Finally after re defining my getters and setters methods according to
  name of my variable this error was resolved

So make sure to redifine getters and setters also.

Answer (score 0):

Change Wrapper class to

```
public Class Wrapper {

          @JsonProperty("wrapper")  // add this line
          private List<Student> students;
}
```

What this does is to recognise the `students` field as `wrapper` key of the json object.

Also I personally prefer using [Lombok Annotations](https://projectlombok.org/) for Getters and Setters as

```
@Getter
@Setter
public Class Wrapper {

          @JsonProperty("wrapper")  // add this line
          private List<Student> students;
}
```

Since I have not tested the above code with Lombok and `@JsonProperty` together, I'll suggest you to add the following code to Wrapper class as well to override Lombok's default getter and setter.

```
public List<Student> getWrapper(){
     return students;
}

public void setWrapper(List<Student> students){
     this.students = students;
}
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829403/deserialize-json-to-arraylistpojo-using-jackson) out to deserialise lists using Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [documentation](https://tedblob.com/jackson-unrecognizedpropertyexception-unrecognized-field-not-marked-as-ignorable/), you can use the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder to build your ObjectMapper:

```
@Autowired
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectBuilder;

ObjectMapper mapper = objectBuilder.build();
String json = "{\"id\": 1001}";
```

By default, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder disables the error unrecognizedpropertyexception.

Answer (score 0):

Json field:

```
 "blog_host_url": "some.site.com"
```

Kotlin field

```
var blogHostUrl: String = "https://google.com"
```

In my case i needed just to use `@JsonProperty` annotation in my dataClass.

Example:

```
data class DataBlogModel(
       @JsonProperty("blog_host_url") var blogHostUrl: String = "https://google.com"
    )
```

Here's article: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-name-of-property

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering.
Would be great if you could add some detail to the code you posted.
What are you trying to achieve, and what is the reasoning behind it?

Posting code is great but a bit of description could significantly help the people who is asking.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this once when my JSON payload included a property that was not recognised by the API. The solution was to rename/remove the offending property.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I tried to suppress the unknown props which did not want to parse.
Sharing Kotlin code

```
val myResponse = jacksonObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .readValue(serverResponse, FooResponse::class.java)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to verify all fields of the class you are parsing in, make it the same as in your original `JSONObject`. It helped me and in my case.

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` didn't help at all.

Comment: it did not help? what you mean? `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` definitely ignores properties which are undefined in java object, but are present in JSON