# Does JSON always have to match a POJO/Bean and vice versa in spring-mvc Rest?

Tags: http, rest, spring-mvc, jackson, http-status-code-400

Every time I call my REST API sending a JSON through PUT, for instance, and there is some different property on it, I got 400 (Bad Request) as a result.

Is there any way to configure spring-mvc to ignore no existent properties when JSON and my Class do not perfectly match?

Here is a sample of a method on my controller:

======

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/include",
    consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
    produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE })

public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Client> 
    inserirClienteSemRedeSocial(@RequestBody Client client) {

    clientDAO.insert(client);

    return new ResponseEntity<Client>(client, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I found the solution here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343477/how-do-you-globally-set-jackson-to-ignore-unknown-properties-within-spring

Answer (score 0):

you can add to your Pojo:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

which will ignore unknown fields

[javadoc](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.4.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'd already tried it.
I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343477/how-do-you-globally-set-jackson-to-ignore-unknown-properties-within-spring