# Force Jackson to ignore isEmpty without JsonIgnore

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson with Jersey in an JAX-RS environment and refer to an external library, to which I only have limited influence. From this external library I use some dataholder/-model as return type and this has an *isEmpty()* method comparable to String.isEmpty()

While serialization is not a problem, the deserialization causes following exception, because the datamodel does not have an *setEmpty()* method and Jackson interprets the *isEmpty()* method as field named *empty*.

```
Unrecognized field "empty" (class de.unirostock.sems.cbarchive.meta.omex.VCard), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "givenName", "organization", "email", "familyName"])
at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@36082d97; line: 1, column: 369]
```

It is not an option to add *@JsonIgnore* to the external library, because that would cause a huge overhead, also I would prefer to not capsulate the dataholder into another one and just delegate the methods or the filter the field in JavaScript.

Is there any other possibility to force Jackson to ignore this *empty* "field"?

Comment: Also see [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToIgnoreUnknown), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343477/how-do-you-globally-set-jackson-to-ignore-unknown-properties-within-spring), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Jackson's MixIn Annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).
It allows you to override default Class configuration.
With this way, you can use `@JsonIgnore` without modifying the external library you're using.

In your exemple :
You have this third party class `de.unirostock.sems.cbarchive.meta.omex.VCard` and you want Jackson to ignore th empty property.

Declare a MixIn class or interface :

```
public interface VCardMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore
    boolean isEmpty();
}
```

Then in your Jackson's `ObjectMapper` configuration :

```
objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(VCard.class, VCardMixIn.class)
```

Comment: Good answer. Could also use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` on the mixin type.

Comment: thanks for your reply! MixIn types are looking exactly like the think I'm looking for, but by using Jersey in a not-Spring environment I don't know how to modify/access the Jackson ObjectMapper. Is it the right way to create a custom *ContextResolver* for *ObjectMapper*?

Comment: I've never used Jackson with Jersey so I wouldn't know. But I guess it's possible to access `ObjectMapper` and customize it anyway. Maybe [this link](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Customizing-ObjectMapper-td6234597.html) can help.

Comment: Yes, I now implemented a custom ContextResolver and use MixIn Annotations.
I mark this answer as valid.

Comment: This looks like a link-only answer (with a broken link).  Using the name, I was able to google and get to [this post](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations), but an ideal answer is self-contained and doesn't actually need the link to work to answer the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks @mgilson You're right, I fixed the link and added some code to anser the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `ObjectMapper`, you can configure it to globally ignore unknown properties.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

The following simple test illustrates this (using [jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.jackson%7Cjackson-mapper-asl%7C1.9.10%7Cjar)).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper om = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
    om.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    String json = "{\"one\":\"hola mundo!\", \"empty\":\"unknown\", \"someOtherUnknown\":123}";
    IgnoreUnknownTestDto dto = om.readValue(json, IgnoreUnknownTestDto.class);
    System.out.println(json+" DESERIALIZED AS "+dto);
}

public static class IgnoreUnknownTestDto {
    private String one;
    public String getOne() {
        return one;
    }
    public void setOne(String one) {
        this.one = one;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return one == null || one.isEmpty();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "one: '"+this.getOne()+"', empty: '"+this.isEmpty()+"'";
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
{"one":"hola mundo!", "empty":"unknown", "someOtherUnknown":123} DESERIALIZED AS one: 'hola mundo!', empty: 'false'
```

Comment: For Jackson 2 it is DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES