# Spring RestController : reject request with unknown fields

Tags: java, validation, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I have the following endpoint :

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> create(@RequestBody Person person) {
        // create person and return id
    }
}
```

Today if I received a request with an unknown field like this :

```
{
    "name" : "Pete",
    "bijsdf" : 51
}
```

I create the person and ignore the unknown field.

How can I check that there's an unknown field and then return a bad request ?

Comment: What JSON library are you using? I think this is the default in Jackson

Comment: Hi Neil, yes it's jackson 2.5.0 that I used

Comment: Yup, Jackson takes care of that. Is your `Person` class annotated with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`?

Comment: There is no annotation on my Person class

Comment: Check this out: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html Default value for `ignoreUnknown` is `false`. That means Jackson (I'm looking at 2.5.0 doc) by default throws exception for missing fields.

Comment: IgnoreUnknown is set to false. I debug and I went to the method reportUnknownProperty of class DeserializationContext and it seems that the DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES is not enable. I'm looking where it is configured ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring (4.1.2-RELEASE) use it's [Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html) that by default disable FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES on overload jackson default behaviour.
See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343477/how-do-you-globally-set-jackson-to-ignore-unknown-properties-within-spring) to configure spring.
Thx all for your helps