# Jackson deserializer priority?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

I have a Spring Boot app that is modeling [ActityStreams](https://www.w3.org/TR/activitystreams-vocabulary) objects and for the most part Jackson's Polymorphic Deserialization works well.

There are 'objects' in the JSON which are references (links) and not JSON objects with type information. For instance
`"actor":"https://some.actors.href/` rather than

```
"actor":{
   "type":"Actor",
   "name":"SomeActor"
 }
```

I've written custom deserializers and and placed them on the fields to deal with this

```
@JsonDeserialize (using = ActorOrLinkDeserializer.class)
private Actor actor;
```

However my `ActorOrLinkDeserializer` is instantiated but never called and Jackson complains with `Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class org.w3.activity.streams.Actor]: missing type id property 'type' (for POJO property 'actor')` which is from the polymorphic deserializer.

It appears that the polymorphic deserialization code takes precedence over my local `@JsonDeserialize` annotation and I need a way to force my code to run first.

I've tried using my own `ObjectMapper` rather than Boot's and there's no difference.

I'd appreciate pointers and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns-out there's a fairly simple solution to this problem using a `DeserializationProblemHandler`.

What I've implemented that works for all test cases so far is

1.

```
objectMapper.addHandler(new DeserProblemHandler());
```

or [register with Spring Boot.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48771520/110452)

2.

```
public class DeserProblemHandler extends DeserializationProblemHandler {
   public JavaType handleMissingTypeId(DeserializationContext ctxt, JavaType baseType, TypeIdResolver idResolver, String failureMsg) {
      return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(baseType.getRawClass());
   }
}
```

3. Add a constructor to each of the polymorphic classes that takes a string argument which is the href.