# PUT and POST fail on unknown properties Spring different behavior

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I am writing Spring Boot application using Spring Data Rest repositories and I want to deny access to resource if request body contains JSON that has unknown properties. Definition of simplified entity and repository:

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    /* getters and setters */
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

I use Jackson's deserialization feature to disallow unknown properties in JSONs.

```
@Bean 
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder(){
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.failOnUnknownProperties(true);
    return builder;
}
```

When I send POST requests everything works as expected. When I use valid fields I get correct response:

```
curl -i -x POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"firstName": "Frodo", "lastName": "Baggins"}' http://localhost:8080/people
{
  "firstName": "Frodo",
  "lastName": "Baggins",
  "_links": {...}
}
```

And when I send JSON with unknown fields application throws expected error:

```
curl -i -x POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"unknown": "POST value", "firstName": "Frodo", "lastName": "Baggins"}' http://localhost:8080/people
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "unknown" (class Person), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "lastName", "firstName")
```

PUT method when using valid JSON returns correct response as well. However when I send PUT request with unknown field I expect Spring to throw error but instead of that, Spring updates object in database and returns it:

```
curl -i -x PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"unknown": "PUT value", "firstName": "Bilbo", "lastName": "Baggins"}' http://localhost:8080/people/1
{
  "firstName": "Bilbo",
  "lastName": "Baggins",
  "_links": {...}
}
```

The error is thrown only when there is no object in database with given id:

```
curl -i -x PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"unknown": "PUT value", "firstName": "Gandalf", "lastName": "Baggins"}' http://localhost:8080/people/100
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "unknown" (class Person), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "lastName", "firstName")
```

**Is it expected behavior or a bug in Spring Data Rest?** How can I throw an error when JSON with unknown properties is passed to application no matter what request method is?

**I've reproduced this behavior by modifying http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/** , the only change I've made is `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` , no other controllers or repositories are in this project.

Comment: How you tried this solution? [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14343479/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14343479/3710490)

Comment: Hmm, now it does not throw exception even with `POST` requests, I guess it works out of the box only with controllers and I have to add some other beans to make it work with repositories. I'll try it.

Answer (score 15):

I think the behaviour you are observing is by design. When a POST is issued you are creating the resource so the JSON is deserialised into your entity type and Jackson is performing this task.

A PUT is working differently in spring data rest. The interesting part is handled in `PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.readPutForUpdate`.

The json is read into a `JsonNode`, the entity is read from the data store and then in `DomainObjectReader.doMerge` the implementation iterates over the json fields. It applies the json to the entity and saves it later in the controller implementation. It also discards all the fields that do not exist in the persistent entity:

```
if (!mappedProperties.hasPersistentPropertyForField(fieldName)) {
    i.remove();
    continue;
}
```

This is my understanding from reading the code. I think you could argue that this is a bug. You could try to report it at spring data rest`s jira - https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST. As far as I know there is no way to customise this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So deserialization does not occur with PUT requests, that's explains a lot. I've made temporary solution using custom `JsonDeserializer` and somehow it works, but I guess I will report that PUT/POST behavior difference as a bug anyway.

Comment: And Spring throws correct error when there is no object in database with given id, so deserialization occurs at this case. Maybe it's by design, but it's not very intuitive in my opinion.

Comment: I agree - it behaves not as expected - but we can explain it and you can be confident that the error is not in your implementation...

Answer (score 5):

When it creates new entity then it converts json directly to java entity object through deserialization process where required validation is involved. But when it updates existing entity then it converts json to `JsonNode` and then merge with existing entity and as expected no validation happens because it is feature for json deserialization to java object.

As workaround you can additionally convert `JsonNode` to entity object and it will work as you expect.

I did quick example how to gain required validation.

go to https://github.com/valery-barysok/gs-accessing-data-rest

*It is not clear solution but you can improve it :)*

This example override existing spring class on classpath `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

**Note** You **must** put this class on classpath before original version.

I did copy-past this class to project and modified `readPutForUpdate` method:

```
private Object readPutForUpdate(IncomingRequest request, ObjectMapper mapper, Object existingObject,
                                RootResourceInformation information) {

    try {

        JsonPatchHandler handler = new JsonPatchHandler(mapper, reader);
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(request.getBody());
        // Here we have required validation
        mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, information.getDomainType());

        return handler.applyPut((ObjectNode) jsonNode, existingObject);

    } catch (Exception o_O) {
        throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException(String.format(ERROR_MESSAGE, existingObject.getClass()), o_O);
    }
}
```

and i used `application.properties` file to configure `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I temporarily solved this problem by using custom deserializers, I force conversion to entity object like in your solution. I have to write deserializer for every entity class but I don't need to mess with classpath that way.

Comment: This just idea for solution that works but you can do it in more right way. You need override `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` configuration where you provide your version of `PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. I tried to do this way but stuck with wrong configuration of `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`.

Answer (score 3):

you can annotate your model with :

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false)
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

Comment: I've annotated it but it does not work, Spring still ignores unknown fields in PUT requests.

Comment: did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`, which has the property `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` set to the `disabled` value by default.

Comment: I've enabled it with `builder.failOnUnknownProperties(true)`. And it does not explain why `POST` requests work and `PUT` don't.