# Spring Boot 1.4 Customize Internal Jackson Deserialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I am using `spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES=true` in the `application.properties` to make deserialization fail on unknown properties but its not working.

I even tried using :

```
@Bean
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
  return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
        .json()
        .featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
        .build();
}
```

But this also didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your code & the data which objects you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Does it work if you define `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545997/put-and-post-fail-on-unknown-properties-spring-different-behavior ?

Comment: @Infinity Thanks for quick reply. I tried that also but didn't work It's a plain project with spring-boot web dependency and a PUT request method to update user (right i'm not hitting database,i'm just logging update request to test method ) and a Plain User Model without any additional annotations.

Comment: So does it work with POST requests?

Comment: @Infinity No, it's not working for POST also.

Comment: @Infinity It's working now, i cleared the m2 cache and rebuild it, maybe it was a version issue. Thanks for your quick replies. I'll check later what was causing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` option is true by default according to [Jackson Documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features).

If you want to disable this setting you may add this option to `application.properties`.

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties = false
```

But in default settings it works as expected. So no need for any setting.

This is one file spring boot application:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestOptionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestOptionApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void formTest(@RequestBody final HelloForm form) {
    }

    public static class HelloForm {

        private String name;

        public String getName() { return name; }

        public void setName(final String name) { this.name = name; }
    }
}
```

This is the integration test for testing rejection on unknown properties.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestOptionApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void testFailOnUnknownPropertiesOption() throws Exception {

        final String text = "{\"name\": \"test\", \"title\": \"test\"}";

        MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(this.context)
            .build()
            .perform(post("/test").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(text))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

*title* property is not defined. So controller sends BadRequest.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It's working now, i cleared the m2 cache and rebuild it, maybe it was a version issue. I'll check later what was causing it. I'll mark this as an answer.

Comment: I tried but it workd with uppercase: spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES.

Answer (score 12):

With Spring boot, by default, unknown properties are ignored during deserialization. 
In order not to ignore these properties, you can :

- Add `spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES=true` in the application.properties
- Use this bean :

  ```
  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
      return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
      .json()
      .featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
      .build();
  }
  ```
- Use this bean :

  ```
  @Bean 
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder(){
      Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
      builder.failOnUnknownProperties(true);
      return builder;
  }
  ```

I have tested these solutions and it works so there is another problem in your code.
Please, can you post your code as ask by javaguy?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It's working now, i cleared the m2 cache and rebuild it, maybe it was a version issue. I'll check later what was causing it. I'm not able to mark both your and Fırat  guy's reply as an answer.  But thanks for quick reply :).

Comment: This answer is more complete, it provides multiple solutions, and in my case (relying on Spring's auto-configuration) Spring was instantiating multiple `ObjectMapper`s and only one of them used the property that I set in `application.properties`. Utilizing the third option from this answer worked for me (although I had to add a `@Bean` for `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` that utilized my custom `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` for it to work).

Comment: If the setting in the application.yaml does not have the desired effect, then check your code. You may have defined an object mapper somewhere. This overwrites the setting behavior by default!