# Spring Field Validation if request has no extra fields

Tags: spring, rest, validation, spring-mvc

I'have a spring-boot rest microservice, I need to validate object if the request has no extra fields.

My dto request class:

```
public class Request implements Serializable {
 @NotNull(message = "{validation.field.notNull}")
 private String field1;
 @NotNull(message = "{validation.field.notNull}")
 private String field2;

/* getter and setter*/
}
```

I want to thorw the MethodArgumentNotValidException if the request contains extra field like this:
POST request:

```
{
 field1 "val1",
 field2: "val2",
 field3: "val3" --error
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot 1.4 Customize Internal Jackson Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874369/spring-boot-1-4-customize-internal-jackson-deserialization)

Comment: The linked question has answers that should be usable in both spring boot and non spring-boot contexts.