# Customize Internal Jackson Deserialization

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

`spring.jackson.deserialization.wrap-exceptions=false` i need this to convert to Bean while not implementing in `Application.properties`.
I tried this but not working.

My reference link [Spring Boot 1.4 Customize Internal Jackson Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874369/spring-boot-1-4-customize-internal-jackson-deserialization)

```
@Bean 
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder(){

        return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options (it's weird if you want to use a custom one for Endpoint deserialization):

#### Override ObjectMapper

```java
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper jsonMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

#### Annotation (The working option for endpoints):

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = YourDeserializer.class)
public class YourClass {
}
```

Deserializer:

```java
class YourDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<YourClass> {
    @Override
    public YourClass deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
       // return YourClass instance;
    }
}
```

#### Take it in your own hands

You could just take a String and use your own ObjectMapper to deserialize the Object