# Bean Ignoring the extra values on the request Body

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-annotations

Here is my Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accountholders/{cardHolderId}/cards/{cardId}", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8", consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public CardVO putCard(@PathVariable("cardHolderId") final String cardHolderId,
        @PathVariable("cardId") final String cardId, @Valid @RequestBody final RequestVO requestVO,
        @RequestParam final Map<String, String> allRequestParams) {
    iCardService.updateCardInfo(cardId, requestVO.getActive());
    return iCardService.getCardHolderCardInfo(cardHolderId, cardId);

}
```

THis is my Request Bean:-

```
public class RequestVO {
    @NotNull
    private Boolean active;

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
```

My request Body:-

```
{
    "active":true,
    "abc":"ignoring this"
}
```

The problem I am having is when i sent an extra parameter in the request Body It seems to ignore the extra value in this case "abc". The code works and give me the response  What I need to throw is 400 BAD REQUEST.

Am i missing something or is their a way to tell it to throw an exception when an extra parameter is passed.

Comment: Which json mapping framework do you use under the hood?

Comment: For this I am not using anything. I just directly map the JSON to the Bean the @RequestBody annotation does that for me. Spring might be using something internally.

Comment: So it is likely Jackson 2 / Faster XML

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
public class RequestVO {
    @NotNull
    private Boolean active;

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: for a global configuration, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14343479/280244

Comment: i tried the solution but i still get the response. i imported the com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties. still same result.