# How to make jackson throw an exception on unknown fields?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I know that jackson can ignore missing fields from a JSON during java serialization and also it can ignore unknown fields too.

**I'd like to know if there's a way to make jackson throw an exception when it find an unknown field.**

I think in jackson internals, probably it uses SAX and just care about "events" related to known attributes, which is also better for performance reasons.

However, detecting a malformed JSON (in a sense that it contains unknown attributes, not in a sense of JSON format itself of course) is helpful specially when users are creating big JSONs by hand.

Comment: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException do we get this ?

Comment: do you want exception to be thrown on unknown field right?

Comment: As @VedX stated, by default UnrecognizedPropertyException is thrown when you are trying to unmarshal JSON.

Comment: you guys are right. my question is not good. this happens because I am using Spring - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343477/how-do-you-globally-set-jackson-to-ignore-unknown-properties-within-spring

Comment: I will close the question since it's dup

Answer (score 3):

You can configure your object mapper.

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
```

Reference [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)

Comment: Is not it enabled by default?

Comment: yes it should be, I am not sure why op is not getting exception, still i think op should give a try