# JAX-RS/JAXB JSON to POJO - Ignore fields in JSON that don't exist in the POJO

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jax-rs

I am working on an API that needs to be able to handle JSON payloads on PUT/POST that may be supersets of the known POJO.

For example:

```
@XmlRootElement
public FruitCounter
{
   int numberOfApples;
   int numberOfOranges;

   public int getNumberOfApples()
   {
      return this.numberOfApples();
   }

   public int setNumberOfApples(int numberOfApples)
   {
      this.numberOfApples = numberOfApples;
   }

   public int getNumberOfOranges()
   {
      return this.numberOfOranges();
   }

   public int setNumberOfOranges(int numberOfOranges)
   {
      this.numberOfOranges = numberOfOranges;
   }
}
```

Would produce JSON along the following lines when a GET is performed:

```
{
   numberOfApples: 4,
   numberOfOranges: 7
}
```

We need to be able to handle a JSON payload like the following, to update the counts for apples and oranges but do nothing for pears.

```
{
   numberOfApples: 9,
   numberOfOranges: 19,
   numberOfPears: 21
}
```

Is there any clean way to do this?

Comment: I think that works has you want, the java could handle numberOfPears properties because it's unknowned. You try and what you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on top of your class

```
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)    
    @XmlRootElement
    public FruitCounter
    {
       int numberOfApples;
       int numberOfOranges;

       public int getNumberOfApples()
       {
          return this.numberOfApples();
       }

       public int setNumberOfApples(int numberOfApples)
       {
          this.numberOfApples = numberOfApples;
       }

       public int getNumberOfOranges()
       {
          return this.numberOfOranges();
       }

       public int setNumberOfOranges(int numberOfOranges)
       {
          this.numberOfOranges = numberOfOranges;
       }
    }
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson) question which seems to be the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

It seems that that would sort the problem.

Currently however we do not have any explicit dependencies on a specific Jackson library and we have only used standard Java 7+ annotations such as those seen here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-frame.html

Am I right in thinking the only way to get something with functionality matching the JsonIgnoreProperties annotation is to use a particular Jackson e.g. codehaus or fasterxml?

Comment: Thanks for your help! We are deploying in Wildfly which uses the fasterxml implementation anyway so it's not too big a deal for us.

Comment: Same here also deploying on wildfly!

Glad I could help :)