# UnrecognizedPropertyException after changing structure of Firebase data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is a little problem with Firebase and Firebase `Snapshot.getValue(mModelClass)`

I have Android app wich contains user list(model class - *User.java*) and interacts with Firebase, structure:

```
-user
--$user_id
---name
---surname
```

I've published the app, and now I want to update my app, add new field to the **user** structure in Firebase:

```
-user
--$user_id
...
--status
```

If I do it, then the published app will crash because old model - User.java doesn't has **status** field and I can't edit pubslished version

Crash text:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "status" (class package.User), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: , "name", "surname"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found answer:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
   public class Foo {
     ...
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455563/2897046