# JAX-RS - avoid new fields in REST requests generate 400 - Bad Request

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jax-rs

I would like to avoid that my REST POST Service (JAX-RS in Spring) returns 400 - Bad Request if I call that service with new fields that it is not able to unmarshal.

Let's do an example:

I have this input request java class:

```
public class PosizioneDto implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Double controvalore;
    private Double quantita;
    private Double prezzo;
    private ContrattoDto contratto;
    private String progressivoMiFid;
    private String codiceProdotto;
    private String ageC;
    private String prodCPadreMifid;
    private String prodCFiglio1Mifid;
    private String prodCFiglio2Mifid;
    private String tipProd;
}
```

if in the input JSON request there were another field (e.g. "_newProperty") I would like that parser wouldn't go in error, but simply wouldn't unmarshal that property.

Is this possible to do? Should I use some ExceptionMapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Jackson parser, then use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation on your POJO class.

You can refer to [Ignoring new fields on JSON objects using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson)