# How to deserialize Json into java object if a property is not present in the java object(should ignore json element)using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am working on a project, where the Json contract may change overtime, If they had new property to the response Json, I might get a exception when deserializing  into java object, How to ignore the new properties and only deserialize elements which are present in java Object, I am using Jackson 1.9.13, Does this version have feature which could ignore the Json element?

Comment: Possible duplicates [Ignoring new fields on JSON objects using Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring new fields on JSON objects using Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways:

1. Add annotation to class:

   ```
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
   class <class_name>{
     ....
     ....
   }
   ```
2. Configure `ObjectMapper`:

   ```
   objectMapper.configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
   ```

Comment: Can I do same for XML using JAXB