# How to get list of data from sqlite and parse into jsonarray and send it to server?

Tags: android, json, android-sqlite

I want to send particular data from database and parse into jsonarray and send it to server. I am able to send dummy data directly to server .Can you tell me the way to send data (parsed jsondata ) into server.?

Comment: I want to `what you tried so far` ? show

Comment: In the same way as dummy data but you need to get this data from SQL .... what had you tried so far? Where is the problem?

Comment: how do you send `"dummy data"`?

Comment: if u able to get data from Sqlite then it is very simple. ! do let me know where do u stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For your approach you should firstly create a array list with all your necessary data send to server. You can parse into json using Jakeson see Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson). Resultant will be your data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to put all your data in the arrayList then use this code

```
private String arrayToJson(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList) {

    //Coverting Arraylist to JsonArray
    List<JSONObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (HashMap<String, String> data : arrayList) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
        jsonList.add(jsonObject);
    }

    JSONArray json_array= new JSONArray(jsonList);

    String json_string= json_array.toString();
}
```

then you can send this to server. And decode this json_string and retrive your data