# How construct list of objects from json string coming from api response?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, gson

Similar question might be asked before on here, but I had no luck and I was wondering how to extract specific objects like `user` in from below json string and then construct an `ArrayList`. However, there is one twist, one of the property directly under `Users` is a random number, which can be anything!!!

Here is how my json string looks like:

```
<code>{
    "_links": {
    },
    "count": {
    },
    "users": {
        "123321": { //*Is a random number which can be any number
            "_links": {
            },
            "user": {
                "id": "123321",
                "name": "...",
                "age": "...",
                "address": ""
                ..
            }
        },
        "456654": {
            "_links": {
            },
            "user": {
                "id": "456654",
                "name": "...",
                "age": "...",
                "address": ""
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    },
    "page": {
    }
}
</code>
```

The java object I would like to transform it to is:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) // Ignore any properties not bound here
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    //setter:getter
}
```

**Note**: The transformation should only consider those two fields (**id,name**), and ignore the rest of the fields from the json response `user:{}` object.

Ideally, I would like to end up with a list like this:

```
List<User> users = resulted json transformation should return a list of users!!
```

Any idea how can I do this please ideally with Jackson JSON Parser/ or maybe GSON?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring new fields on JSON objects using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson)

Comment: Well not really coz I’ve a random object name which can be anything!

Comment: Also that answer doesn't show how to construct `List<User>` list!

Answer (score 1):

Since the user keys are random, you obviously can't map them to a named Java field. Instead, you can parse the top-level object as a map and the manually pull out the user objects.

```
public class UserWrapper {
    private User user;
    public User getUser() { return user; }
}

public class Root {
    private Map<String, UserWrapper> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        List<User> usersList = new ArrayList();
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            UserWrapper wrapper = map.get(key);
            usersList.add(wrapper.getUser());
        }

        return userList;
    }
}

Root root = parseJson();
List<User> users = root.getUsers()
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

[jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice) transformer is your friend. Use `shift` with wildcard `*` to capture  arbitrary node value and then standard mappers (Jackson /gson) .