# Parsing a JSON to nested class

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I am having a JSON in which I have all the data as key-value pair. But my POJO is with nested class. How can I map the single level JSON into the nested class objects?

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "prototype" : {
            "name": "Deepak"
            "departmentId": "10"
            "departmentName": "IT"
            "address": "Bangalore"
            "state": "Karnataka"
   }
}
```

And my POJO looks like this:

```
class Prototype{
    String name;
    Department dept;
    Address address;
}

class Department {
    Integer departmentId;
    String departmentName;
}

class Address {
    String address;
    String state;
}
```

I tried using ObjectMaper but it only maps the name, other fields are not getting mapped. Does anyone knows how to achieve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping a flat map to a nested pojo in jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579978/mapping-a-flat-map-to-a-nested-pojo-in-jackson)

Comment: I have read this post already. I am looking for something if I can tell to Object mapper using som annotation or other configuration

Comment: if you use Jackson, you can define custom deserializer [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization).