# copy one array list of jsonobject to another without referencing to same

Tags: java, json, reference

I tried like below.
I want to copy one array list of jsonobject to another without referencing to same....,
Can anyone explain me what i am doing wrong??

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> a = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
JSONObject aa = new JSONObject();
aa.put("key1", "old");
aa.put("key2", "old");
aa.put("key3", "old");
a.add(aa); `T`

ArrayList<JSONObject> b = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
b = a; 
b.get(0).put("key1", "new");
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: `List<JSONObject> b = a.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());`  Java-8 can do it in one line.

Comment: This also affects both list.,

Comment: Hey Sambath, did my answer solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
b = a; //Remove this line
```

This is where the problem is. You are referencing the same object. You need to create a new object instead.

Rather than doing above, you should do,

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> b = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(a);
```

**UPDATE**

The above `ArrayList<JSONObject> b = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(a)`method will won't work as this will create a shallow copy of the list. The actual object would remain the same. For creating deep copy you will have to create a copy of each of the objects and add to a new list. Or you could use serialize/deserialize as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701076/copying-variables-from-one-pojo-to-another/55701244#55701244) 
or,

You can do this if there is one layer of nested objects. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575477/deep-copy-of-a-list-with-custom-objects-in-java/48575635)