# Will an error be produced if JSON response does not match with Java class?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Say that I have the following Java class

```
public class ResponseObj
{
  private String a;
  private String b;

  //constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

Next I do a REST call to an API

```
ResponseEntity<ResponseObj> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://api.com/employee/24",
                  HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, ResponseObj.class);
```

and the JSON response from the API is as follows

```
{
  "a" : "data1",
  "c" : "data2",
  "d" : { "prop" : "data3"},
  "e" : ["data4","data5"]
}
```

Will the code produce an error since the JSON response structure is different than `ResponseObj`? Or will it be fine but `ResponseObj` won't have properties of "c", "d", and "e" from the JSON response, and property "b" in `ResponseObj` will have a value of null?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself with a sample code?

Comment: Couldn't start up my app to test it out. Still trying to figure out what's wrong with the build. So I post this question here.

Comment: Make DTO and relevant constructor for result mapping.

Comment: You can ignore unkown properties in response - check https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455563/1776132

Answer (score 0):

It depends on some circumstance. The fields you want to map must be the same name (or you can provide alternative name for example with `@JsonAlias`) and type as in the json.
You can create `ObjectMapper` and set the requiered behaviour. If you set the `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` to `false`, then it will ignore the properties in json, which doesnt mapped into your data class. `FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES`can control the behavior on missing fields like `b`.
There are lot of properties and annotations which can control the behaviour of serialization/deserialization.