# How to not include a field in Request object while communicating to an endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pojo

I am having a POJO UserRequest.java which has 4 fields in it and my use case is that I need to send this POJO as request object with 3 fields to REST Endpoint-1 and as another request object with 4 fields to REST Endpoint-2 (as this one needs 4 fields as input).

```
public class UserRequest(){

  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  private String field3;
  private String field4;

}
```

So I want to use same POJO for both REST Endpoints with 'field4' to be passed only in 2nd Endpoint. I tried using @JSONIgnore annotation over 'field4' but it sends 'field4' as null in 1st Endpoint but 1st Endpoint fails as it does not want 'field4' at all. Please suggest how can I use same POJO for both Endpoints.

Comment: JsonIgnore ignores the field for de-/serialization, you should look into direction: ["json ignore null"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11757487/592355), ["json ignore unknown"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5455014/592355) ..and advanced: "json view jackson"

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the fourth field as `Optional`. This way you can pass it to both endpoints, but don't have to pass `field4` for Endpoint-1.

```java
public class UserRequest(){

  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  private String field3;
  private Optional<String> field4;

}
```

Another option is JsonNullable from the [jackson-databind-nullable](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/jackson-databind-nullable), but I usually prefer using `Optional` as it is a standard java type.

```java
public class UserRequest(){

 private String field1;
 private String field2;
 private String field3;
 private JsonNullable<String> field4;

}
```