# org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "id" (Class Criteria), not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, android, json, annotations, jackson

I am getting this exception when I am trying to parse Json to Java pojo object. The object graph has couple objects.

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "id" (Class Criteria), not marked as ignorable
```

I wanted to see, in which case this exception will come, where could be the problem is it in the object graph??

I am doing this in my android project I am not using annotations here I am not sure how to add this field as ignorable.

Comment: You don't show the code of your POJO nor the JSON you try to deserialize; difficult to tell in these conditions. But the error seems to be that there are object members not present in the POJO definition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jackson with JSON: Unrecognized field, not marked as ignorable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486787/jackson-with-json-unrecognized-field-not-marked-as-ignorable)

Answer (score 16):

You don't show any code, so...

Anyway, try and add this annotation to the class you deserialize:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will also happen if you have defined the field in your POJO, but do not have a getter AND setter methods defined. Ignoring the field may have unintended consequences.

This does look to be a duplicate of: [Jackson with JSON: Unrecognized field, not marked as ignorable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486787/jackson-with-json-unrecognized-field-not-marked-as-ignorable)