# how to ignore class definition in json data using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I am using org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper to deserialize json data sent a client. But client is sending class definition in the JSON. Is there a way to ignore class definition info in the json and convert it to required Java Bean using
ObjectMapper.

Note :  Could not fix client code or define a class with same package structure as sent by client in the server side due to cross release supports. 
So finding a easy way to ignore class definition in the payload and convert it to required java bean as per server side impl.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486787/jackson-with-json-unrecognized-field-not-marked-as-ignorable/12730655#12730655

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate the response java class with

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

to ensure that unmapped properties in the json will be not considered during unmarshalling

Comment: This can be used to ignore some properties in json. Lets say JSON has class definition info and actual data, then I want to parse only actual payload attributes and ignore class definition.