# How to print the attributes from request in response in java using RestFull webservice?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have been following a tutorial of RestFull webservices, but i am not able to understand some concepts.
Here is my PersonServiceImpl class.

```
    @Path("/person")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{

    private static Map<Integer,Person> person = new HashMap<Integer,Person>();


    @Override
    @Path("/add")
    @POST
    public Response addPerson(Person p) {
        Response response = new Response();

        if(person.get(p.getId())!=null) {
            response.setStatus(false);
            response.setMessage("Person already exists");
        }
            person.put(p.getId(),p);
            response.setStatus(true);
            response.setMessage("Person added sucessfully ");
            return response;
    }

    @Override
    public Response deletePerson(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPerson(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Person[] getAllPerson() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
   }
```

I have made some changes in the code to produce and consume json file.
This is my person class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int id;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

And this is my Response class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Response {

    private boolean status;
    private String message;
    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return "" + message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message= message;
    }


}
```

And here is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>JAXRS-EXAMPLE</groupId>
    <artifactId>JAXRS-EXAMPLE</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>0.99</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I want to know :

1. How to print the values of person class in the response?
2. How the json values are mapped to the java attributes and where?
   3.If i enter a extra value in the json request what happens to that value?

The link to the tutorial: https://www.journaldev.com/9170/restful-web-services-tutorial-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is not a good idea to implement your own `Response` class. The class [`javax.ws.rs.core.Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) exists and should be used for a generic response of a JAX-RS method.

**Regarding 1:** If by '*print*' you mean *return the JSON representation of the `Person` instance*, just do this:

```java
    @Override
    public Person getPerson(int id) {
        Person personForId = person.get(id);
        if (personForId == null) {
          thrown new NotFoundException();
        }
        return personForId;
    }
```

The `Person` instance will be automatically serialized to a JSON representation.

**Regarding 2:** Since `Person` follows the Java Bean convention of getters and setters, JSON elements will be mapped by name to bean properties. This JSON

```
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "some message"
}
```

will be mapped to a `Person` instance with `status = true` and `message = "some message"`.

There are plenty of annotations you can use on the class, on its fields or getters or setters that let you tweak this behaviour.

**Regarding 3:** This behaviour depends on the JSON serialization library you use. The widely used Jackson library provides the [`@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486787/jackson-with-json-unrecognized-field-not-marked-as-ignorable). Other libraries may have different annotations for this purpose.