# Deserialize using Object mapper with invalid field ignore

Tags: java, objectmapper

I am not a Java programmer but keen to know how to achieve a feature which would ignore one or more invalid fields while de-serializing. In my case, the `byte[]` is send by a legacy system and hence no control over data correction (on encoding side or to send default in case of missing). This means, I need to anticipate invalid data/missing data within the `byte[]`.

Following code serialize payloads but throws exception upon receiving invalid (wrong encoding, null etc).

```
   public class LDeserializer<T> implements Deserializer<T> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final Class<T> myType;

    public LDeserializer(final ObjectMapper objectMapper, final Class<T> myType) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.myType = myType;
      }

    public LDeserializer(final Class<T> myType) {
        this(new ObjectMapper(), myType);
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(final String sometext, final byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(bytes, myType);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new SerializationException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

*Question:* In my case, I can safely ignore invalid values while serialization. However, I am not sure how to instruct my serializer to ignore invalid fields (irrespective of its type). So that the serializer would emit object even thou the constructed object is not complete.

*Note*: `ObjectMapper` is the type I am using here to support serialization. However, I am free to use any helper types that can be used instead `ObjectMapper`. The only concern here is how to ignore invalid fields (irrespective of its type).

Please advise

Comment: What are **invalid fields** in your case? If the fields are just not known in the class [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730655/8178842) might be a solution.

Comment: @Tobias, For eg: The payload has string data. But this string data is not encoded correctly while storing. This means, when I receive such poorly formatted string, my deserializer throws exception while reporting ''invalid char found while deserializing'.