# How to map a JSON string which includes members named long and short

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I need to map a JSON string which includes values named long and short:

```
"status": {
   "long": "Finished",
   "short": "F",
   "elapsed": 90
}
```

I tried the following class:

```
public class Status {

    @JsonProperty("long")
    public String _long;
    @JsonProperty("short")
    public String _short;
    @JsonProperty("elapsed")
    public Object elapsed;

}
```

with the command:

```
objectMapper.readValue(resBody, Response.class);
```

response contains the status part:

```
{
    "response": {
        "id": 157016,
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "date": "2019-08-10T11:30:00+00:00",
        "timestamp": 1565436600,
        "status": {
            "long": "Long Value",
            "short": "LV",
            "elapsed": 20
        }
    }
}
```

But still I get the following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
> Unrecognized field "long"

How can this be fixed? I do not have control on the JSON format.

Comment: One question to avoid possible misunderstandings : `"status"` is one of the properties inside the `Response` json like `{"status": {}, ...}`?

Comment: @dariosicily I updated the question with an extended example. Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what `@JsonProperty()` is meant for, and your example JSON+class parses properly. Probably it's not `Response.class` which you should provide in the `readValue()` call, but another class, which contains a `public Response response;` inside.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is obviously not a perfect solution to the problem, but one may find it as a helpfull workaround:

Since I don't care about these values, I'll just rename their names and adapt the class members name accordingly:

on the json string resBody I get as a response I will do the following

```
@NotNull 
private static String mitigateLongAndShortValueNames(String resBody) { 
   resBody = resBody.replaceAll("\"long\":", "\"longValue\":"); 
   resBody = resBody.replaceAll("\"short\":", "\"shortValue\":"); 
   return resBody; 
}
```

and change

```
public class Status {

    @JsonProperty("long")
    public String _long;
    @JsonProperty("short")
    public String _short;
    @JsonProperty("elapsed")
    public Object elapsed;

}
```

to

```
public class Status {

    public String longValue;
    public String shortValue;
    public Object elapsed;

}
```

It worked for me!

Comment: Certainly it is possible to solve the issue also in this way,

Comment: Certainly :) But currently this is good enough for me...

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to solve the problem is select the json part you are interested combining the [`ObjectMapper#readTree`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree-java.lang.String-) method that converts your json to a `JsonNode` object and then select the part of the `JsonNode` object you are looking for  with the [`JsonNode#at`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#at-java.lang.String-) method which matches the `/response/status` path expression like below:

```
//it contains only the status labelled node of your json
JsonNode statusNode = mapper.readTree(json).at("/response/status");
```

After you can use the [`ObjectMapper#treeToValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode-java.lang.Class-) method to convert the `JsonNode` to your `Status` class obtaining the expected result:

```
JsonNode statusNode = mapper.readTree(json).at("/response/status");
Status status = mapper.treeToValue(statusNode, Status.class);
//ok, it prints {"long":"Long Value","short":"LV","elapsed":20}
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(status));
```

Comment: Dario, for me it is better actually to ignore it. I don't need it. If there is a way to ignore this part of string in json it would be the best for me. If possible, I can skip this string part.

Comment: Ok, I know what I can do. Since I don;t care about these values, I'll just rename their names and adapt the class memebers name accordingly:

Comment: @NotNull
    private static String mitigateLongAndShortValueNames(String resBody) {
        
        resBody = resBody.replaceAll("\"long\":", "\"longValue\":");
        resBody = resBody.replaceAll("\"short\":", "\"shortValue\":");
        return resBody;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The full exception message should look something like this: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "long" (class ...), not marked as ignorable (n known properties: ...)`

If it is the case that you're not interested in certain properties, it's easier and cleaner to `ignore` those during parsing. Either with an annotation on the data class or a DeserializationFeature on the objectmapper.

See [Jackson with JSON: Unrecognized field, not marked as ignorable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486787/jackson-with-json-unrecognized-field-not-marked-as-ignorable)

Answer (score 0):

Extending the comment: there's no problem with `Status` and `"status":...` parts, `@JsonProperty()` is meant to handle the renaming. You probably pass the wrong class to `readValue()`.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestClass test= mapper.readValue(
                "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"response\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"id\": 157016,\r\n" + 
                "        \"status\": {\r\n" + 
                "            \"long\": \"Long Value\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"short\": \"LV\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"elapsed\": 20\r\n" + 
                "        }\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "}",TestClass.class); // <-- here, it's not Response, but an outer class
        System.out.println(test.response.id);
        System.out.println(test.response.status._long);
    }
    public Response response;         // <-- containing "response"
    static public class Response {
        public long id;
        public Status status;
    }
    static public class Status {
        @JsonProperty("long")
        public String _long;
        @JsonProperty("short")
        public String _short;
        @JsonProperty("elapsed")
        public Object elapsed;
    }
}
```

Displays

> ```
> 157016
> Long Value
> ```

as expected. Kept only `id` from the outer object for the sake of brevity.