# Parse String line and store into DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pojo

I receive a String line through Kafka that looks like that:

```
type: x, code: y, time: 25
```

is it possible to map this String to a java DTO? I only dealt with JSON string before and used object mapper to convert JSON to DTO but never a one line String. I have a DTO class that has type, code and time as fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with **Jackson (`ObjectMapper`)**.

```java
// Raw data.
String data = "type: x, code: y, time: 25";

// Mapper raw data to map.
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.asList(data.split(","))
        .stream()
        .map(s -> s.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors
                .toMap(
                        s -> s[0].trim(),
                        s -> s[1].trim()));

// Jackson's ObjectMapper.
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final MyDTO myDTO = objectMapper.convertValue(map, MyDTO.class);
```

1. Split entry pairs and convert string array to `List<String>` in order to use `java.lang.Collection.Stream` API from Java 1.8,
2. Map the resulting string list `key:value` to a string array with **`[0]`** as key and **`[1]`** as value,
3. Use `.collect(..)` terminal method from stream API to mutate,
4. Use the `Collectors.toMap()` static method which take two function to perform mutation from input type to key and value type,
5. All that's left is to convert the `Map` to `DTO` with the `ObjectMapper`.

**If there is a value in the raw data** that is not in the `DTO`, [see here to ignore it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546047/2039546)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write some custom logic.

Try this.

(Assuming, type & code are char & time is int)

```java
String s = "type: x, code: y, time: 25";
final String[] parts = s.split(",");
DTO dto = new DTO();
for (final String part : parts) {
     final String[] keyValue = part.trim().split(":");
     final String key = keyValue[0].trim();
     final String value = keyValue[1].trim();
     if ("type".equals(key)) {
          dto.setType(value.charAt(0));
     } else if ("code".equals(key)) {
          dto.setCode(value.charAt(0));
     } else if ("time".equals(key)) {
          dto.setTime(Integer.parseInt(value));
     }
}
```