# Unrecognized properties error not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

> ERROR:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "status" not marked as ignorable (11 known properties: "method", "sequenceNo", "statusMessage", "timestamp", "supportMessage", "customerId", "data", "statusCode", "path", "transactionId", "_links"])

CODE:

```java
@Data @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) 
public class KYCScoreIndResponse {
    private String customerId;  
    private String statusCode;
    private String statusMessage;   
    private String supportMessage;   
    private String transactionId;   
    private KYCData data;  
    private String sequenceNo;   
    private String path;   
    private String method;   
    private String timestamp;   
    @JsonIgnore private HttpStatus httpStatus;   
    private Links _links;
}
```

How to solve the error i tried using `@jsonproperty` of each parameter  but not working

Comment: I think you have used the wrong property name somewhere: "status" != "httpStatus".

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486787/jackson-with-json-unrecognized-field-not-marked-as-ignorable

Comment: @TheincredibleJan Technically true, but it won't help. The problem here is using the right property name, not ignoring the property which is the only thing suggested in that question's top answers.

Comment: Can you explain your issue first?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply @JsonIgnoreProperties to all class in you application then the best way it is override Spring boot default jackson object.

In you application config file define a bean to create jackson object mapper like this.

```
@Bean
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return mapper;
    }
```

Now, you don't need to mark every class and it will ignore all unknown properties.